# Pass Variable into CMD

Tags: command-line, script, window

I have setup a script and tested that it work with user input via `set /p` but now I want to pass that variable automatically to the cmd.

**Script w/ user input:**

```
@ECHO OFF

set /p id="Enter Rom: "

start /d "G:\Emulators\N64\Project64" Project64.exe "G:\Emulators\N64\Roms\%id%"
```

**What I want to pass to the CLI:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set id = "Goldeneye 007.v64" & "C:\script.cmd"
```

Comment: So will a user execute the script and always input the value then? I just want to make sure you need the user set variable value to be what the rest of the batch script uses, correct?

Comment: No, perhaps I should have explained more, I'm looking to create a "universal" cmd that I can pass the ROM name too before running the CMD

Comment: I only tested w/ User input, now I want to just have it be automated w/o user input at all

Comment: Okay, so you can just make the batch script accept an argument rather than setting it and use that variable as `%~1`.

Comment: So you can use `set id=%~1` and then pass the argument to the batch as .................................................................... `C:\script.cmd "Goldeneye 007.v64"`

Comment: I wrote up an answer for you with more clarity so let me know what you think when you get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [batch arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and pass the value of the ROM to the call of the batch script when you execute it such as `C:\script.cmd "<Value Argument>"`.

Rather than using `set /p id="Enter Rom: "` use `set id=%~1` and that's all that is needed to allow the first argument passed to the script to be used for the value to set the `id` variable.

### Batch Script Example

```
@ECHO OFF

set id=%~1

start /d "G:\Emulators\N64\Project64" Project64.exe "G:\Emulators\N64\Roms\%id%"
```

### Argument Passed to Batch Script Example

```
C:\script.cmd "Goldeneye 007.v64"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

  > %* in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. %1 %2 %3 %4
  >   %5 ...%255)  only arguments %1 to %9 can be referenced by number.